# Java int array incremented with start and end points

Tags: java, arrays

I need an array that takes a given int (x) that is the starting number and then count up to a bigger number (y) Any ideas?

```
    int x = 5;
    int y  = 10;
    int b     = y - x;
    int[] a   = new int[b];

    for (int i=0; i<b; i++) {
        a[i] = i;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
    //Should be:  a = {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    //I get the right length array but not the right vaules
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignment `a[i] = i` assigns values 0,1,2.. to the array elements. Instead, we need to start from `min` value (5 in this case). We can do it by declaring anoter variable and incrementing it in the loop (so that the value of original argument won't change) like below:

```
int start = x;
for (int i=0; i<b; i++) {
        a[i] = start++;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
```

Comment: That was a typo, the correct code is up now. Thanks!

Comment: yes it is very close now I think I'm still a little confused Im getting an out of bounds exception.

Comment: No never mind it was a typo in the for loop. Your solution worked :)

Comment: I'll select it as soon as it lets me. Thanks!